# Request Promise not returning a value (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

I have been trying to get this to work for while now, my request promise is not returning the streamer it has found. When i console.log(streamer) inside of the .then part of the request it works. Any ideas?

```
function getStreamerByName(name){
var streamer;
var options = {  
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=" + name,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Client-ID': 'CLIENT_ID',
    }
};
requestP(options)
//SPREAD
    .spread(function(res, body) {
        streamer_data = JSON.parse(body);
    })
//THEN
    .then(function (body) {
        streamer = ({
            twitch_id: streamer_data["data"][0]["id"],
            name: streamer_data["data"][0]["display_name"],
            image: streamer_data["data"][0]["profile_image_url"],
            description: streamer_data["data"][0]["description"]
        });
        Streamer.create(streamer);
        return streamer;
    })
//CATCH
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return streamer;
    });
}
```

Comment: "*When i console.log(streamer) inside of the .then part of the request it works*" - why not just do that? Yes, you cannot use `streamer` outside of the `then` callback, as that code would execute when the promise was not yet fulfilled-

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the promise chain:

```
function getStreamerByName(name){
var streamer;
var options = {  
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=" + name,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Client-ID': 'CLIENT_ID',
    }
};
//A return was added here
return requestP(options)
//SPREAD
    .spread(function(res, body) {
        streamer_data = JSON.parse(body);
    })
//THEN
    .then(function (body) {
        streamer = ({
            twitch_id: streamer_data["data"][0]["id"],
            name: streamer_data["data"][0]["display_name"],
            image: streamer_data["data"][0]["profile_image_url"],
            description: streamer_data["data"][0]["description"]
        });
        Streamer.create(streamer);
        return streamer;
    })
//CATCH
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return streamer;
    });
}
```

When you all this function externally, you'll also need to use a .then() to get the result or use an async function and await.

so

```
async caller() {
   var value = await getStreamerByName('stuff')
}
```

or

```
caller() {
    getStreamerByName('stuff').then((result) => { //do stuff })
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but i just tried this and its not getting the streamer still, its coming up with an error message saying: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
function getStreamers() {
            getStreamerByName(search).then((streamer) => {
                console.log(streamer)
            })
        }
getStreamers();
```

Comment: Did you modify your getStreamerByName to return the promise?

Comment: No, but im trying to return the streamer not a promise

Comment: You can't. You always have to return a promise. If you don't want to return the promise and use it directly, you'll need to use the async/await construct. 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-beautiful-node-js-apis-using-async-await-and-the-firebase-database-befdf3a5ffee

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getStreamerByName (name) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Your code
   });
}

Var myStreamer = getStreamerByName ('myStreamer');
```

Comment: just tried putting my my code in that and it didnt work, it said "SyntaxError: Unexpected token function"

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted, particularly if they cut 'n' paste your solution into their existing code.